# How do I show Blogger comment form on mobile?

Tags: css, mobile

The comment form of my Blogger blog is invisible in mobile devices. It only shows up whenever a first comment is posted using desktop. If comment is zero, the comment form is not shown in mobile.

I've tried the following css, to no avail

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
#comments-block {display: block;}
.comment-footer {display: block;}
.comment-form {display: block;}
}
```

HTML

```
</div>
<dl class='comments-block' id='comments-block'>
  <dd class='comment-footer' collapseable>
  </dd>
</dl>
<div class='comment-form'>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it being overwritten? Did you try with a higher select value or using !important?

Comment: It's working now. Thanks to לבני מלכה.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
.blogger-iframe-colorize {
display: block !important;
}
```

See here:https://www.gurubest.com/2014/11/how-i-fixed-blogger-comment-form-for.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Comment form now shows on my blogger mobile version.

Comment: happy to help:)